# Google Search Console is not fetching the sitemap correctly?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap

Search Console is not fetching the sitemap when it is named as “Sitemap.xml”, after we renamed it as “Sitemapnew.xml” sitemap is submitted successfully??

4,630 URL”S were discovering even after we removed those URL'S from the sitemap why??

What will be reason for these issues?? Kindly provide some suggestions.

[image]

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if you use the fetch as Google option to see how the crawler interacts with the url that throws an error.